# Vuetify - Throws 'Module parse failed:' errors while building

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js

I have been trying to solve this problem but i couldn't find any solution.

I created project using `vue init webpack-simple my-project`

I fallowed the same steps that mentioned in https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start#webpack-install

After running `npm run dev`, i got these errors for all the vuetify components

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/main.sass (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--4-2!./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js?indentedSyntax!./node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/main.sass)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'indentedSyntax'. These properties are valid:
   object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }
    at validate (D:\project\webpack-vue\my-project\node_modules\sass-loader\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:50:11)
    at Object.loader (D:\project\webpack-vue\my-project\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:36:28)
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/main.sass 4:14-222 13:3-17:5 14:22-230
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/framework.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/vuetify.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/vuetify/src/directives/ripple/VRipple.sass (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--4-2!./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js?indentedSyntax!./node_modules/vuetify/src/directives/ripple/VRipple.sass)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'indentedSyntax'. These properties are valid:
   object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }
    at validate (D:\project\webpack-vue\my-project\node_modules\sass-loader\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:50:11)
    at Object.loader (D:\project\webpack-vue\my-project\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:36:28)
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/src/directives/ripple/VRipple.sass 4:14-240 13:3-17:5 14:22-248
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/directives/ripple/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/directives/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/vuetify.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

**package.json:**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.11",
    "vuetify": "^2.1.10"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "fibers": "^4.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "sass": "^1.23.7",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.4",
    "webpack": "^4.13.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  }
```

I haven't modified any thing in the webpack, just added few lines that vuetify suggests(Available in above link).

Comment: so, what is `../../util/helpers`?

Comment: The component code itself is like that, its not some thing i add/modified. You can see the code in `VAutocomplete.js` in the node_modules.

Comment: Its not problem with specific `VAutocomplete` component. Error is throwing for all the components. I can see that `it needs appropriate loader to handle file type`.

Comment: Have you tried following https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start#vue-cli-3-install ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV i tried creating application with `vue create my-app` and it works. There is not problem with vuetify as well. But i already have a project created with `vue init webpack-simple my-project`, with vuetify version 1.5.11. i am trying to update to 2.X. There the problem comes in.

Comment: There is a migration guide at https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/releases-and-migrations#migration-guide

Comment: I tried now also, its almost same steps that i did. I updated the Error log in the above issue, take a look at it. I think there is problem with loder.

Answer (score 1):

The Link you posted mentions you need `sass-loader@^7.0.0`.

> // Requires sass-loader@^7.0.0

While you are using `"sass-loader": "^6.0.6"`.

The issue you are facing came up on [github issues](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/761) a few times and is most likely related to sass version.

1. remove `sass` and `sass-loader` from your package.json
2. run `npm i` or `yarn`
3. run `npm i sass sass-loader@^7.0.0` or `yarn add sass sass-loader@^7.0.0`
4. run `npm run dev`

Comment: The Errors that i previously posted related to webpack and i updated it and resolved those issues. Few other issues comes in, i modified the error log in the above issue. Updated the sass and sass-loader, same problem. Posted the updated package.json. Please take a look at it.

Comment: could be related to style tag or indentedSyntax param.
please have a look at: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4513

Comment: also maybe try to install exactly ^7.0.0, as mentioned in the doc, updated my answer accordingly

Comment: I tried many things nothing seems to be working using webpack installation.